# Pandas DataFrame get substrings from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column named "KL" with for example:

```
sem_0405M4209F2057_1.000
sem_A_0103M5836F4798_1.000
```

Now I want to extract the four digits after "M" and the four digits after "F". But with `df["KL"].str.extract` I can't get it to work.

Locations of M and F vary, thus just using the slice `[9:13]` won't work for the complete column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `str.extract`, here's how:

```
>>> df['KL'].str.extract(r'M(?P<M>[0-9]{4})F(?P<F>[0-9]{4})')
      M     F
0  4209  2057
1  5836  4798
```

Here, `M(?P<M>[0-9]{4})` matches the character `'M'` and then captures 4 digits following it (the `[0-9]{4}` part). This is put in the column `M` (specified with  `?P<M>` inside the capturing group). The same thing is done for `F`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split` to achieve this, probably a better way exists:

```
In [147]:
s = pd.Series(['sem_0405M4209F2057_1.000','sem_A_0103M5836F4798_1.000'])
s

Out[147]:
0      sem_0405M4209F2057_1.000
1    sem_A_0103M5836F4798_1.000
dtype: object

In [153]:
m = s.str.split('M').str[1].str.split('F').str[0][:4]
f = s.str.split('M').str[1].str.split('F').str[1].str[:4]
print(m)
print(f)

0    4209
1    5836
dtype: object

0    2057
1    4798
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex:

```
import re

def get_data(x):
    data = re.search( r'M(\d{4})F(\d{4})', x)
    if data:
        m = data.group(1)
        f = data.group(2)

        return m, f

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': ['sem_0405M4209F2057_1.000', 'sem_0405M4239F2027_1.000']})

df['data'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: get_data(x))

>>
                          a          data
0  sem_0405M4209F2057_1.000  (4209, 2057)
1  sem_0405M4239F2027_1.000  (4239, 2027)
```